# Meteor.js mongodb version

Tags: mongodb, meteor

This may be a dumb question, but I am confused about something. I have downloaded mongodb 2.6.4(latest) version to my mac, and deleted old mongodb folder which had executables and other stuff. But whenever I execute 'meteor mongo' command from my meteor.js application, it is opening MongoDB shell version 2.4.9, not the latest one. Why is this happening? Where is this old version is coming from? How can I use the latest version in meteor.js application?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meteor includes its own version of mongodb as a part of its bundle when you ran `curl https://install.meteor.com | sh`

It does this so its not a hassle to install and they can bundle the correct supported versions with it.

Meteor doesn't yet officially support 2.6.4 on the account of some oplog differences, though you can get it to work without the oplog without any issues, and with the oplog with a couple of issues.

Comment: I do not need oplog now, can you give some tips about how I can integrate my application with meteor 2.6.4. I googled it, but could not find much about it.

Comment: Provide the `MONGO_URL` environment variable to your local mongodb instance, i.e `MONGO_URL="mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017" meteor` to start your app up.

Comment: Thanks, one more thing. Now, when I do meteor mongo, I can not connect to database as expected because it is not local. So, where can I see my db name, and collections now? Because in mongo shell, when I do show dbs, I do not see anything related to my meteor application.

Comment: Found it. Db name is called admin. Is there a way that I can change it?

Comment: Yup you can use `MONGO_URL="mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/meteor"` instead which will use the `meteor` database. Check out this doc for the full spec on the connection string: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/

Comment: Yes you can no longer use `meteor mongo` since it is designed for the bundled version of mongodb. You would have to use `mongo` as part of your local bundle to connect to this 2.6.x db.

Answer (score 2):

Meteor 1.0.x supports both 2.6 and 3.0.  It ships with 2.6 locally.

http://info.meteor.com/blog/meteor-104-mongo-cordova-template-subscriptions