# Is it possible to upgrade meteor's mongo installation?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I want to use mongo 3.2 with meteor. My mongo installation currently states that it is at 2.6.7

```
meteor :: (cron-tasks*) » meteor mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.7
connecting to: 127.0.0.1:3001/meteor
Mongo-Hacker 0.0.8
```

Would it be possible to upgrade it to 3.2? I have not seen docs on this anywhere, [only a question on using 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25681912/meteor-js-mongodb-version). Is it possible to manually upgrade to 3.2 from the current version?

(Meteor version is tagged at 1.2 currently)

Comment: I had a similar question once - you can specify a different db, though it doesn't address your question of upgrading the pre-installed version. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30110100/how-to-specify-meteor-mongodb-version-on-local

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do it. Simply create a new local database and then connect to it by setting `MONGO_URL`

```
$ mongod
$ MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/my_other_db meteor
```